# How to prevent application from crashes in Rpi?

Tags: services

I replace `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` file to run my script that runs my application. But when my application crashes never run again. 
I tried before run my app in a service, but as my app have GUI service doesn't run at startup..

How can i run my app and prevent if crashes?
Thanks

Comment: Can u have a try of systemd user service? http://superuser.com/questions/759759/writing-a-service-that-depends-on-xorg  2nd answer of this link

Comment: Like i said in the question, i tried a systemd service..

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479)

Answer (score 1):

You could specify `watch my_script` instead of just `my_script` in the autorun file. `watch` will re-run a command again and again when it terminates. Note that you won't be able to terminate your application properly (you'd have to run `killall watch` or something similar on the terminal).

If you need to avoid restarting your application if it exits properly (assuming it exits with a zero return value), you could instead specify:

```
bash -c "until my_script; do echo $?; done"
```

Answer (score 0):

user based systemd service can help you. Try this example systemd service.

file location and name "~/.config/systemd/user/mygui.service".

```
[Unit]
Description=My GUI Auto Start APP
After=display-manager.service
[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
RootDirectory=/home/rajesh/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myguiapp
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Enable the service by

```
systemctl --user enable mygui.service
systemctl --user start mygui.service
systemctl --user status mygui.service
```

NOTE:

GUI Applications some time required more environment variables. Set Proper environment variables and if possible use a environment file

Comment: Why difference between root directory and  execstart?

Comment: You can Ignore RootDirectory parameter, it is my app related param. to know more you can refer https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html. Is this work for you?

Comment: I don't have systemd directory in .config directory. I'm running other service and it is in /etc/systemd/system/

Comment: I tried this before, and the problem is that my app needs to be run at a specific directory not in root directory and if execstart isn't a absolute path it gives an error..

Comment: if .config is not there then just create it using "mkdir -p ~/.config/systemd/user", also you can use "WorkingDirectory" in systemd service file

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl --user enable ConsolaGrafica.service`
`Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused `

Comment: Why to `Restart=always`? It never help to fix a buggy service. It only waste performance in case of a failing service.